# Unable to SSH to google compute VM instance after a stop/start

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Bitnami Wordpress (single site) installed VM on Google Cloud instance that was working perfectly until I stopped/Started the instance.
After doing so, my website went down, and I can no longer SSH to it using the browser nor OSX Terminal. I get the following message:
"We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22"

I double checked the Firewall on Google cloud - which I did not change from default - and everything seems ok.

It is not Pingable and I even tried to trace route to the server but it reaches to 216.239.42.191 then stops before reaching my VM.

So I tried to connect using the serial Console and it is flooded with:

```
Sep 30 07:44:17 localhost kernel: [43306.942210] IPv4: martian source  10.128.0.2 from 74.125.73.34, on dev eth0
Sep 30 07:44:17 localhost kernel: [43306.949531] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 00    
    B.....B.......
[43317.271565] IPv4: martian source 10.128.0.2 from 10.128.0.1, on dev eth0
[43317.278571] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 06        B.....B.......
Sep 30 07:44:28 localhost kernel: [43317.271565] IPv4: martian source 10.128.0.2 from 10.128.0.1, on dev eth0
Sep 30 07:44:28 localhost kernel: [43317.278571] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 06    
    B.....B.......
[43377.265708] IPv4: martian source 10.128.0.2 from 10.128.0.1, on dev eth0
[43377.272733] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 06        B.....B.......
Sep 30 07:45:28 localhost kernel: [43377.265708] IPv4: martian source 10.128.0.2 from 10.128.0.1, on dev eth0
Sep 30 07:45:28 localhost kernel: [43377.272733] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 06
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

1 - I would recommend that you read the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror) on how to handle the "Unable to connect on port 22" error message.

More details on how to troubleshoot SSH issues and workarounds can be found [in the following link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

2 - Since you’ve said that this occurred right after you’ve stopped/started the instance, I highly suspect that you’ve assigned an [ephemeral external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#ephemeraladdress) to the VM instance.

If this is the case, I would suggest that you look at changing the VM instance IP address from an ephemeral IP address to a static IP address. More details on how to reserve a static External IP address to the VM instance can be found [in this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

3 - By looking at the serial console logs, I can see that the issue here is related to the packets having a Martian origin. So, every packet received on the VM, whatever was the source or destination, was just discarded by the Kernel for these packets being flagged as having a Martian source.

You may read more about it [in this article.](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=3923798) There are a few solutions offered. Alternatively, there are other resolution steps [in this article.](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeRouter/Help-with-martian-packets/td-p/846962)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1- I tried everything in the link but it did not work   2- It had been set as Static IP from the beginning.